# Confused About C# Distance Converter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, distance, converters

I'm working on an application that lets the user convert distances to and from inches, feet, and yards. I'm having a bit of a problem with the output. Here's my code:

```cs
private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    int fromDistance = 0;
    int toDistance = 0;

    fromDistance = int.Parse(distanceConverterTextBox.Text);
    string distanceInput = fromListBox.Items.ToString();
    string distanceOutput = toListBox.Items.ToString();

    switch (distanceInput)
    {
        case "Inches":
            switch (distanceOutput)
            {
                case "Inches":
                    toDistance = fromDistance;
                    break;

                case "Feet":
                    toDistance = fromDistance / 12;
                    break;

                case "Yards":
                    toDistance = fromDistance / (3 * 12);
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case "Feet":
            switch (distanceOutput)
            {
                case "Inches":
                    toDistance = fromDistance * 12;
                    break;

                case "Feet":
                    toDistance = fromDistance;
                    break;

                case "Yards":
                    toDistance = fromDistance / 3;
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case "Yards":
            switch (distanceOutput)
            {
                case "Inches":
                    toDistance = fromDistance * 3 * 12;
                    break;

                case "Feet":
                    toDistance = fromDistance * 3;
                    break;

                case "Yards":
                    toDistance = fromDistance;
                    break;
            }
            break;

    }
    convertedDistanceLabel.Text = toDistance.ToString();
}

private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

And here's what the app looks like:

[image: Distance Converter application window]

My control names if they help:

- The input `TextBox`: `distanceConverterTextBox`
- The output `Label`: `convertedDistanceLabel`

I've even tried not declaring the `int`s to be 0, then I tried one and/or both, and the output is still zero no matter what. It can really be a simple case of accidentally using the wrong control name, but I really don't know what else to do at this point, so extra eyes will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the function, and step through it (`F10` in VS). You can look at what the values are for your variables. I'm guessing that your issue is with `.Items.ToString()` lines when you're trying to get the values of the controls. I don't think it returns what you're expecting it to return. This link has some information on how to get the values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `fromListBox.Items` and `toListBox.Items` are collections. You probably want the current `SelectedItem` of both. With a ListBox, you usually call `string theItemText = [ListBox].GetItemText([ListBox].SelectdItem)` to retrieve the item selected as text. It also depends on what you put inside those ListBoxes... You should put a breakpoint in `fromDistance = (...)` and inspect the values you get.

Comment: Also remember that integer divided by integer is *integer*. `3 / 12` is not 0.25, because that's not an integer. It's zero.  If you intend integer divided by integer to be double or decimal, then do the arithmetic in doubles or decimals.

Comment: Also, never use `Parse` for human-provided inputs because humans can provide non-numbers, which will crash. Use `TryParse`, and check the output for correctness.

Comment: Your switches all lack a `default`.  Add one to each! It will help you find bugs.  Something like `default: Debug.Fail("Unexpected value:" + distanceInput); break;`

Comment: @EricLippert - In general, when should we throw and log an exception instead of making use of a Debug Fail/Assert? Since in Release the Debug calls will be elided, there could be issues that did not occur during the debugging/testing but that appear in a particular production environment. Isn't it better to have some clear indicator of failure in the production environments too?

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Great question; a comment is not the best place for a long answer. The short answer is: "throw" statements should be *testable*; there should be a way to make a test case demonstrate that the method throws when it should. Debug assertions should be *not testable*. There should never be a way to make a test case assert. **Exceptions tell you about the caller's mistakes. Assertions tell you about the truth.** The purpose of an assertion is to tell the developer when something they believe to be true is actually false.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: For example, consider a method `void Sort(int[] a)` which sorts an array. `if (a == null) throw ArgumentNullException...`  is testable; there is a way you can call the method that causes the exception. But suppose just before the return we have `Debug.Assert(a.Length < 2 || a[0] <= a[1]);` That is, either the array has zero elements, or it has one element, or the sorted array has the first element smaller than the second.  That is a **truth** about the sorted array. There should be **no situation whatsoever** in which that assertion is violated, so no test case.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: So in this specific example, if there is a test case which can demonstrate that the inputs or outputs are not as expected, then there should be a throw, and a corresponding unit test which verifies that the throw happens when it should. If there is not, then an assertion tells the developer when they have accidentally violated a program invariant, by, say, adding a new item but not adding the corresponding case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are converting all the `items` to `string`, you should convert only the `selected item` to `string` or in my opinion use their `id`s

For `Selected Item`

```
listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

for the Selected Index use

```
listBox.SelectedIndex
```